# Having connection issue Hibernate 3.0 with MySQL

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring

I am getting this error. I have my hibernate connections and MVC all setup correct I believe.
I heard MySQL drivers have an issue for database connection.

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/AdministrativeApplication] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection] with root cause
java.sql.SQLException: Unknown database 'testDB'
```

My hibernate configuration file

```
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
     xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    ">
 <!-- Load Hibernate related configuration -->

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" /> 
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testDB" />
    <property name="username" value="myroot"/>
    <property name="password" value="*****"/>
    <!-- connection pooling details -->
    <property name="initialSize" value="1"/>
    <property name="maxActive" value="5"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">

    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
    <!-- Declare a transaction manager-->
    <props>
    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
    </props>
    </property>
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
    <list>
    <!--   all the annotation entity classes -->
    </list>
    </property>
    </bean>
<!-- Declare a transaction manager-->
 <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager"
          p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory" />    
    </beans>
```

Please let me know what 
I could do to resolve this error.

I further added a new java file to test

```
import java.sql.*;

   public class Connect
   {
       public static void main (String[] args)
       {
           Connection conn = null;

           try
           {
               String userName = "root";
               String password = "******";
               String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testDB";
               Class.forName ("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance ();
               conn = DriverManager.getConnection (url, userName, password);
               System.out.println ("Database connection established");
           }
           catch (Exception e)
           {
               e.printStackTrace(System.out);
               System.err.println ("Cannot connect to database server");
           }
           finally
           {
               if (conn != null)
               {
                   try
                   {
                       conn.close ();
                       System.out.println ("Database connection terminated");
                   }
                   catch (Exception e) { /* ignore close errors */ }
               }
           }
       }
   }
```

I get this error . Also I started the MySQL console with this command. 
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqld.exe"

I get this error

```
java.sql.SQLException: Unknown database 'testdb'
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2975)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:798)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.secureAuth411(MysqlIO.java:3700)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1203)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2572)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1485)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:266)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
    at Connect.main(Connect.java:15)
Cannot connect to database server
```

Can some please help resolve this. 
i ran netstats no luck. I do not see at what port MySQL is listening at.

Thanks again .
Dhiren

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am getting this error.

This means you did something wrong.

> I have my hibernate connections and MVC all setup correct I believe.

See my previous comment - you did not do everything correctly.

> I heard MySQL drivers have an issue for database connection.

Nope - MySQL drivers work fine if you set them up properly.  You're doing something wrong, and you'll make progress faster if you take that attitude.

Before you run Java, start up the MySQL client, log into MySQL.  If you can't, Java won't be able to, either.  See if the daemon is up and running.

See if you have that database available.  If not, create it.

If it is created, make sure that you have the tables you need and the user you're logging in as has appropriate permissions.

Comment: I have the db and I can login wuth that user correctly into MySQL directly but not using jdbc .

Comment: Does "testDB" exist?  Or is it "testDb"?  Case matters.

Comment: I made a simple stand alone jdbc application in Java should connect to SQL. That too is failing not sure if the MySql port is important . How does my SQL connectionstring look   like. this is what I have jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testDB

Comment: Yes, the port matters.  When you set up MySQL, did you take the default port or did you change it?  If you type 'netstat' in a command shell, what port is MySQL listening on?

Comment: Does a local My SQL need to be started . I checked netstats and I did not see MySQL listening on any port

Comment: Yes, of course MySQL needs to be started.  If there's no daemon listening on that port, there's nothing to connect to.

Answer (score 2):

You could [create a database](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-database.html) named "testDB" in your MySQL instance.